# Parse arbitary date formats in Python (including rfc3164)

Tags: python, date-parsing

PHP has the amazing [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) function which takes pretty much anything and turns it into a time.

I'm looking for something similar in Python?

As an example of why: I'm parsing syslogs which have the dumbest format ever (aka [rfc3164](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt)) which omits a year and includes a space-padded day-of-month.

Currently in Python I'm doing this:

```
import datetime
d='Mar  5 09:10:11' # as an example

# first remove the space, if it exists
if d[4] == ' ':
   d = d[0:4] + d[5:]
# append this year (I know, it could be last year around Dec/Jan!)
d =  str(datetime.datetime.now().year) + ' ' + d

# now we can feed it strptime
date = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S")
```

This is really ugly.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`dateutils`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) module:

```
In [12]: d = 'Mar  5 09:10:11'

In [13]: import dateutil

In [14]: dateutil.parser.parse(d)
Out[14]: datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 5, 9, 10, 11)
```

Comment: Surprising Python doesn't have this in core. But thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it's the dumb "oh you can't accept this answer for 36.4 seconds" thing that made me forget. Must ask on meta what the purpose of those limitations is one day!